# SAVE button on VF page not working, it remains on EDIT and doesnt go back to main page on CASE object, I used standa

Tags: visualforce

I have a basic visualforce page on the Case object which is just displaying some fields for a user when creating new records or open existing record. 
When I click on Save, the record gets Save or Update existing however after Saving it doesnt go back to Case page, it remains on edit.

THERE IS NO CONTROLLER CREATED

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" sidebar="false" >

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >

          <apex:pageblockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton Value="Save" action="{!Save}" />
                <apex:commandButton Value="Cancel" action="{!Cancel}"  />
            </apex:pageblockButtons>

          <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputField value="{!Case.type}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Case.reason}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!Case.status}"/>
           </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>    
    </apex:form>   
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Please post the controller as well, otherwise it tricky to troubleshoot. As a second suggestion, try to add a `<apex:pageMessages />` to know if there is an exception being thrown

Comment: Hi Sergio Alcocer, I tried with "<apex:pagemessages ></apex:pagemessages>" however no difference. I am trying in the new, blank salesforce account. There are no validation however no jon.